# Symfony2 form processing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble processing my contact form, a simple one though. I have spent much time trying to figure out what is wrong with my code but I've not been able to find a way out. My object is not receiving data. I'm having the following exception:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO contact (email, name, message, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, "2016-09-19 00:08:48"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null

Below is my code:

```
 <form action="{{ path('ap_platform_contact') }}" method="POST" class="marginBottom25px" id="contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Votre email">
                {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nom </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Votre nom ou celui de votre société">
                {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Message</label>
        <textarea id="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-control" name="message" rows="3"></textarea>
        {{ form_errors(form.message) }}
    </div>
    <!--
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdICQcUAAAAAMKjB3Cet82jKHwb_4S-ms8Wz-iE"></div>
    </div>
    -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn tf-btn btn-success">{{ 'Envoyer'|trans }}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The controller:

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    // Retrieving POST data
    //$postData = $request->request->get('email');

    $contact = new Contact();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);

    if ($form->handleRequest($request)) {

        /*if ($this->get('ap_platform.antispam')->isSpam($contact->getMessage())) {
            throw new \Exception('The field email is either empty or its content is too short');
        }*/

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($contact);
        $em->flush();

        //var_dump($contact->getEmail());exit;

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Votre message a été envoyé !');

        $mailer = $this->get('mailer');

        $message =  \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Message venant du formulaire de contact de chyqat.com')
            ->setFrom('chyqat@chyqat.com')
            ->setTo('patrickbassoukissa@yahoo.fr')
            ->setBody("Nouveau message provenant de ".$contact->getName()."<br>  Adresse Email : <strong>".$contact->getEmail()."</strong> <br>Son message:<br> <i>".$contact->getMessage()."</i>")
        ;

        $mailer->send($message);
    }

    return $this->render("APPlatformBundle:Public:contact.html.twig", array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

ContactType.php file:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email',       'email')
            ->add('message',     'textarea')
            ->add('name',        'text')
        ;
    }

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Advertproject\PlatformBundle\Entity\Contact'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'advertproject_platformbundle_contact';
}
}
```

Contact object:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Patrick
 * Date: 11/30/15
 * Time: 11:58 AM
 */

namespace Advertproject\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Tests\Validator\Constraints as PasswordValidation;



/**
 *
 * Class Contact
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact")
 * @package Advertproject\PlatformBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100)
     *@Assert\NotBlank(message="Veuillez fournir une adresse email")
     * @Assert\Length(max=100)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=1000)
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="string")
     */
    protected $message;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @param string $email
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set message
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get message
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me finding out what is wrong with my code?

Below is what I got after running `var_dump($form->getData())` before calling flush() method

> object(Advertproject\PlatformBundle\Entity\Contact)#1955 (5) { ["id":protected]=> NULL ["email":protected]=> NULL ["name":protected]=> NULL ["message":protected]=> NULL ["date":protected]=> object(DateTime)#1956 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-09-18 20:49:32.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" } }

Comment: Do you have any setters in `Contact` or only `__construct` function?

Comment: @pazulx You're right to ask that question, so I have edited my post to include the complete code of my Contact object. But as you can see, I have all the setters properly written to assign values to Contact attributes

Comment: As Yogesh is pointing out, you need to actually use the correct form-names in your form html.

Comment: Those are twig functions, which have to do with the front-end side, I'm not sure there will be any impact on the backend side if replaced with simple HTML or other Template engine code. FOSUserBundle doesn't use Twig functions but the code works great. Anyway, I'm going to try.

Comment: @PatrickBass - That is not true, there will be an impact if the names of the form elements are incorrect. Which looking at your twig templates is definitely the case. An easy way to prove this is to use form_widget() to generate your form field, the generated field names will be markedly different than what you have defined in your template. Also there is nothing special in your template that cannot be generated using those twig functions - so you may as well use them instead of fighting the framework. Martin's answer explains your problems very well.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for your note. This issue is now resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use following code in your html.twig page

```
     <div class="panel-body">
         {{ form_start(form) }}
         {{ form_errors(form) }}
         {{ form_widget(form) }}
         {{ form_end(form) }}
     </div>
```

check following [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-the-form) for more ways to render forms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is now resolved by following your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the answer by Togesh Patil is incomplete.

I see two problems with the code:

1. **Template**

   When using form you need to provide correct input names so Symfony Form can automatically fetch submitted data from `$request`. If you don't want to use the default `form_widget()` Twig helpers you can just grab names for each input and render them as you wish:

   ```
   <input type="email" name="{{ form.name.vars.full_name }}" class="...">
   ```

   Then don't forget to include the CSRF token (if you haven't disabled CSRF protection manually):

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="{{ form._token.vars.full_name }}" value="{{ form._token.vars.value }}">
   ```

   Btw, helper `form_end(form)` prints CSRF token automatically for you. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/csrf_protection.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-the-form
2. **Controller**

   This is not how you should validate a Form in a controller, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions:

   ```
   $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
   $form->handleRequest($request);

   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
       $contact = $form->getData();
       // persist and so on ...
   }
   ```

   Notice using `ContactType::class` instead of `new ContactType()`.

   Also note, that expression `if ($form->handleRequest($request)) {` is always `true` because `handleRequest()` returns `$this`. See https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Form.php#L486.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. My issue is resolved now